# Using ray to parallelize simulator python

Tags: python, simulator, ray, concurrent-processing

I'm new to ray and I'm trying to parallelize the simulator that I have developed. Here an example of my simulator obviously its more complex.

```
import some_library
import sim_library_with_global_object

class Model(object):
    def __init__(self,init_vals):
        #initialize object using some of the global_object from sim_library.
        #the Model object have it's own variables not global

    def do_step(self,time):
        #calculate Model step using the global_object from sim_library
        #edit the Model variables with respect to the step


class ManyModel(object):
    def init(self):
        self.models=[]

    def add_model(self,init_vals):
        model = Model(init_vals)
        self.model.append(model)

    def step(self,time):
        for model in self.models:
            model.do_step(time)

    def get_data_step(self):
        data=[]
        for model in self.models:
            data.append(model.myvalues)
        return data



sim=ManyModel()
inits=[] #####list of init_vals
times=[] ####list of times to simulate
for init in intis:
    sim.add_model(init)

for time in times:
    sim.step(time)
    step_data=sim.get_data_step()
```

So far I have tried to use ray with the decorator `@ray.remote` over the `Model` class (1) and the `ManyModel` class (2) in these two ways:

**(1)**

```
############################## (1) ###############
import some_library
import sim_library_with_global_object

@ray.remote
class Model(object):
    def __init__(self,init_vals):
        #initialize object using some of the global_object from sim_library.
        #the Model object have it's own variables not global

    def do_step(self,time):
        #calculate Model step using the global_object from sim_library
        #edit the Model variables with respect to the step


class ManyModel(object):
    def init(self):
        self.models=[]


    def add_model(self,init_vals):
        model = Model.remote(init_vals)
        self.model.append(model)

    def step(self,time):
        futures=[]
        for model in self.models:
            futures.append(model.do_step.remote(time))
        return futures

    def get_data_step(self,futures):
        data=[]
        while len(futures)>0:
            ready, not_ready = ray.wait(ids)
            results=ray.get(ready)
            data.append(results)
        return data

ray.init()
sim=ManyModel()
inits=[] #####list of init_vals
times=[] ####list of times to simulate
for init in intis:
    sim.add_model(init)

for time in times:
    sim.step(time)
    step_data=sim.get_data_step()
```

and **(2)**

```
########################## (2) #################

import some_library
import sim_library_with_global_object

class Model(object):
    def __init__(self,init_vals):
        #initialize object using some of the global_object from sim_library.
        #the Model object have it's own variables not global

    def do_step(self,time):
        #calculate Model step using the global_object from sim_library
        #edit the Model variables with respect to the step

@ray.remote
class ManyModel(object):
    def init(self):
        self.models=[]
        self.data=[]


    def add_model(self,init_vals):
        model = Model(init_vals)
        self.model.append(model)

    def step(self,time):
        for model in self.models:
            model.do_step(time)

    def get_data_step(self):
        self.data=[]
        for model in self.models:
            self.data.append(model.myvalues)
        return self.data


ray.init()
sim=ManyModel.remote()
inits=[] #####list of init_vals
times=[] ####list of times to simulate
for init in intis:
    sim.add_model.remote(init)

for time in times:
    sim.step.remote(time)
    future=sim.get_data_step.remote()
    step_data=ray.get(future)
```

In both ways, I'm not getting any benefit from using ray library. Can you help me in the usage?

**Updates of Method (1)**
The problem of the first approach is that I receive  this message of warning

`2020-11-09 11:33:20,517    WARNING worker.py:1779 -- WARNING: 12 PYTHON workers have been started. This could be a result of using a large number of actors, or it could be a consequence of using nested tasks (see https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/3644) for some a discussion of workarounds.`

With 10 x `Model`  this are the performance results:
With no use of ray:
10 x `Model`  ->  `do_step` 0.11 [s]
With ray (1):
10 x `Model`  ->  `do_step` 0.22 [s]

Moreover, every time I create an Actor with the method (1) it makes a copy of all the global_objects fo the imported libraries and the ram consumption get crazy. I need to lunch simulation with more than 100k+ `Model` objects.

In general, I did not understand if in ray it is a good idea to create many actors or not.

Answer (score 2):

Zooming in on some of the core elements

```py
ray.init()
sim=ManyModel.remote()

for time in times:
    sim.step.remote(time)
    future=sim.get_data_step.remote()
    step_data=ray.get(future)
```

The most important point is that you are creating only one Ray actor (in the line `sim=ManyModel.remote()`). Ray actors execute tasks submitted to them sequentially (by default), so creating one actor doesn't create any opportunities for parallelism. To get parallelism with Ray actors, you need to create and use multiple actors.

A second point is that you are calling `ray.get` inside of the for loop. This means that on every iteration through the for loop, you are submitting a task and then calling `ray.get` which waits for it to finish and retrieves the result. Instead, you will want to submit multiple tasks (perhaps inside a loop) and then call `ray.get` outside of the loop.

Comment: My intent is to retrive the results of each time step for all the Models inside ManyModel. I have tried the configuration (1) that creates many actors and the (2). But with none of the tow, I got any performance increase.